# Extracting part of name from string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was trying to extract the lastName, firstName, middleName from Name column which contains whole name format.

here's the sample names which I'm trying to extract:

```
DELA CRUZ, JUAN PONCE SR. ENRILE
ATIENZA, ROBERTO JR. SANTO
GONZA, MARK ANTHONY, DELLY-LO
```

I want to extract them like these:

```
    LastName    | FirstName       | MiddleName
    DELA CRUZ   | JUAN PONCE SR.  | ENRILE
    ATIENZA     | ROBERTO JR.     | SANTOS
    GONZA       | MARK ANTHONY    | DELLY
```

This is my script so far

```
DECLARE @Name    VARCHAR(50) = 'DELA CRUZ, JUAN PONCE SR. ENRILE'

SELECT
SUBSTRING(@Name, 0, CharIndex(',', @Name)) LastName,
REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@Name), CharIndex(' ', reverse(@Name))-1)) MiddleName
```

I also having a problem when extracting middle with -LO suffix.

thank you

Comment: I hope you now have learned to never store data as comma separated values.

Comment: As it considers names, [this](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) is a valuable read

Comment: @jarlh Yes, extracting this kind of data is pain, but I'm not the one who designed this database

Comment: You say you are having problems with `-LO`, so what do you want to do with it? Looks like you just want to ignore it, so you are changing peoples names, then?

Comment: sorry forget to say  -LO is not part of their names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String operations are a real pain in SQL Server.  I recommend using `APPLY` to define intermediate values, if you have to use them:

```
select v1.lastname, rest, 
       (case when v1.rest like '%,%'
             then left(rest, charindex(',', rest) - 1)
             else left(rest, len(rest) - charindex(' ', reverse(rest)))
        end) as firstname,
       (case when v1.rest like '%,%'
             then stuff(rest, 1, charindex(',', rest) + 1, '')
             else stuff(rest, 1, len(rest) - charindex(' ', reverse(rest)) + 1, '')
        end) as lastname
from t cross apply
     (values (left(names, charindex(',', names) - 1), stuff(names, 1, charindex(',', names) + 1, ''))
     ) v1(lastname, rest);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=be70bc43f55bfb6090ea97eb24f1c690) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Try this below logic (modified your one)

```
DECLARE @Name    VARCHAR(50) = 'DELA CRUZ, JUAN PONCE SR. ENRILE'

SELECT
SUBSTRING(@Name, 0, CharIndex(',', @Name)) LastName,
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(RIGHT(@Name,LEN(@Name)-CharIndex(',', @Name))), 0, CharIndex(' ', REVERSE(RIGHT(@Name,LEN(@Name)-CharIndex(',', @Name)))))) MiddleName,
REPLACE(REVERSE(RIGHT(REVERSE(RIGHT(@Name,LEN(@Name)-CharIndex(',', @Name))),LEN(REVERSE(RIGHT(@Name,LEN(@Name)-CharIndex(',', @Name))))-CharIndex(' ', REVERSE(RIGHT(@Name,LEN(@Name)-CharIndex(',', @Name))))+1)),',','') FirstName
```

Comment: still having a problem with this kind of name format GONZA, MARK DELLY -LO. Delly should be in MiddleName

Comment: Output for your given name is -

LastName - "GONZA" MiddleName - "Delly" FirstName - "MARK DELLY -LO."
 

Is not it expected?

Comment: there is some cases where firstname is only 1 part ex: Mark and MiddleName is DELLY -LO. it's being read as Mark Delly. Didn't expect to also have cases like these. thank you anyway